# Second derivative in coordinate invariant form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, tensors, fluid-dynamics

To solve stationary, incompressible, inviscid and irrotational flow around a circular cylinder, I am using general coordinates. Since the flow is symmetrical, we only consider the upper half of the plane.

I derived a PDE and proper boundary conditions in the physical domain (left image) given by $G := \{(x_1,x_2 : R_1^2 \leq x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq R_2^2, x_2 \geq 0\}$. This PDE is $\Delta \phi = 0$, where $\phi$ is the perturbation potential.
[image: Physical and logical domain]

In general coordinates, the expression for $\Delta \varphi$ can be expressed as (using the Einstein summation convention)
\begin{align*}
 \Delta \phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi^\alpha}\left(\sqrt{g}g^{\alpha\beta}\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\xi^\beta}\right),
\end{align*}
where $\xi(\mathbf{x})$ is the (inverse) coordinate mapping and $g$ is the (contravariant) metric tensor.

On the cylinder itself, the BC is given by 
$$
    \nabla\phi\cdot\mathbf{n} = -U_\infty n_1,
$$
where $U_\infty$ is is the free stream velocity in the $x_1$ direction. In general coordinates, this BC becomes
$$
    \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \xi^2} = -U_\infty (\mathbf{a}^{(2)})_1,
$$
where $\mathbf{a^{(\alpha)}}$ is the contravariant basis vector.

The other boundary condition (horizontal left and right of the cylinder) is given by
$$
    \frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial x_2^2} = 0 \ \text{ and } \ \frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial x_1\partial x_2} = 0
$$
and I would like to also write this is in coordinate invariant form (in terms of the covariant/contravariant basis vectors and the metric tensor), but I have no idea where to start. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the covariant derivative of a scalar is a gradient because scalars don't depend on basis vectors, hence

$$\nabla_j \varphi=\partial_\varphi$$

The next covariant derivative will depend on the connection so assuming the Levi-Civita connection, withthe Christoffel symbols, the covariant derivative will be:

$$\nabla_i \nabla_j \varphi=\nabla_i \partial_j \varphi=\partial_i \partial_j \varphi-\partial_k \varphi~\Gamma^{k}_{ij}$$